# How can I use different background and foreground images for each camera?

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine, image

I have an experimental scene I've been working on as I'm learning Blender.  (I've already asked about some camera and image issues in [Why doesn't my Eevee rendered image match my view through the camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/202296/101310))  I added background and foreground images to one camera.  It took a while to get them to show up.  I did a lot of research and found that the images specified within the Camera settings don't show up unless you include them as sources in Nodes in Compositing.  So I did that.  They showed up, just like I wanted to.  It took a lot of experimenting and help, but I got it to work.

Then I went to another camera and the same background and foreground images in Camera 1 show up in Camera 2 as well when I do a render.  My understanding is that by setting up both the background and foreground images in the Compositor, they are part of the scene and will show up for any camera.

Now I'm confused.  From my perspective now, a background or foreground image won't show up unless it's a source in the Compositor, but if it's a source in the Compositor, then it seems to show in every camera.

How do I add a background and foreground image so it'll be visible from Camera 1 and no other camera?

In this particular file, I'd like the images to show up with Camera, but not with Camera.001.

Blend file: [image]

Comment: Using the parented images indicated in previous answer and backface culling you don't need to use the compositor at all. Each camera is parent of its foreground and background and backface culling makes the images invisible to the other camera.

Comment: @lemon - Are you saying that, at least in Eevee, if I specify the background and foreground images in a camera, I don't need to do anything else?  Is it that simple?  I could swear I did that and it didn't work, but I'm gong to do it again.  It's always possible I did something wrong before!

Comment: Tango, no. The last part of my previous answer is about adding planes with image textures on them. Adjust their positions and scales to the camera and parent them to the camera. The blend file at the end of the answer is about that.

Comment: @lemon - Okay, going over that, but I'll probably fall asleep before I finish reviewing it.  So many things to keep track of and all of them are so interconnected!

Comment: Can you add more details about the overall context of what you want to do with these two cameras at the end (that could avoid leading you in the wrong direction)?

Comment: Right now, while experimenting no this, I'm ignoring all the positioning issues for the background image, so unless there's some reason that will change what I can and can't see, I'm going to ignore the positioning issue for now.

Comment: The goal on this is to be able to print blueprints.  I'll be using a foreground image to frame it and include info like my name and contact info, the job site (which is always going to be my address unless friends ask me to draw up plans - I'm NOT a professional!).  Each camera will be set for a view of the project from one angle and the image produced will be one page on the plans.  (That's the reason for the dimensions - so the rendered image will fit on a US legal page with 100 dpi resolution.)  The background image will be used for notes and specs that are needed on that page of the plans.

Comment: ok. So no vfx effects at all. What I propose above should work very simply. Just image as plane placed in front of camera finally.

Comment: @lemon - so use a plane for both background and foreground images and place the planes in the appropriate place for the camera to see them and frame them as needed?

Comment: Yes, again give a look at the blend file i've attached in the answer to your previous question.

Comment: @lemon - Thank you.  Previously I was looking at your nodes and using them.  So now I'll focus on this part within that file.

Comment: @lemon - This raises multiple questions.  I don't want to drain a lot of your time, but is it possible I could move this to chat so I could go over some points more thoroughly?  I don't need real-time responses, but I don't want to stretch this into a long line of comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116712/discussion-between-lemon-and-tango).